# Vitamio ffmpeg version

Tags: android, ffmpeg, vitamio

Has anybody succeeded in modifying the version of ffmpeg used in Vitamio? I have applied a patch that works on linux, and also compiled it as libffmpeg.so for android. How do I get Vitamio to run from this library instead of the one included in the bundle?

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: Please use tag vitamio ..

Answer (score 3):

### Requirements

The Vitamio 3.0 is built with Android *NDK r8b*, so it's recommended to use NDK r8b to build your custom FFmpeg. According to developers feedback, there're many issues and crashes if other NDK revisions used.

### Build FFmpeg

At first clone FFmpeg-Android library from our GitHub http://github.com/yixia/FFmpeg-Android. Then tweak the *FFmpeg-Android.sh* to fit your own need.

The most common scenarios are that you want to compile several certain modules of FFmpeg in your app, without any other masses. In this situation, all you need to do is to modify the `FFMPEG_FLAGS` in the shell script. All the available parameters are well documented in FFmpeg's configure script `configure --help`.

In rare cases, if you want to patch FFmpeg, you need more work, I just think you may have all the knowledges to do that. Indeed, you just need to understand the FFmpeg-Android.sh or craft your own build script.

At last, run FFmpeg-Android.sh in bash. It's a bash script which may work in zsh too.

### Bundle libarm.so

Find the file *res/raw/libarm.so* in VitamioBundle

```
=> file res/raw/libarm.so 
res/raw/libarm.so: 7-zip archive data, version 0.3
```

Yes, you find the magic, it's a 7-zip file, so unzip it in anyway and replace each libffmpeg.so with your own builds.

```
60 <=> armv6
61 <=> vfp
70 <=> armv7
71 <=> neon
```

Finally archive all data to *libarm.so* again.

**Source:** https://www.vitamio.org/en/2013/Tutorial_0509/13.html

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the useful points of an answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion). You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.